# Windows Service can't access certain information

Tags: java, winapi, native, jna

I have created a service. It works fine.. installs, starts, stops etc. I am trying to capture something using JNA. Here is the code of what I am capturing.

```
PointerType hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow(); // then you can call it!
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
log.info("Window title is: "+Native.toString(windowText));
```

Logger stores this which is not expected

```
17:54:59,472  INFO rkactivityclientlog:33 - Window title is: 
17:55:00,477  INFO rkactivityclientlog:33 - Window title is:
```

If I am trying to capture intbyreference it prints 0.

Edit:: If I am trying to get any other object like date.. its coming properly.. like

```
18:04:15,885  INFO rkactivityclientlog:39 - Time is: Wed Jun 12 18:04:15 IST 2013
```

but it is not capturing native variables :(

I can however capture the required information in stdout.

Any help Please..

Comment: If your service does not have desktop access, or access to the process which owns the window, you'll probably won't be able to access the data.

Comment: So how to give permission to my service..??

Answer (score 1):

From Windows Vista onwards, services do not have access to the desktop.  See the MSDN article on [Interactive services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Services now run in a different session to any users who are logged in.

> Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista.

In order to access window information on a user's desktop you will need to write an application that can be executed in the user specific context.  That application will then need to communicate with your service through some RPC mechanism.

The reason for this is that services typically run with very high privileges.  In the past, interactive services have been the source of security vulnerabilities.  In particular, attackers were able to use a technique called [shatter attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack) to escalate privileges.

> A shatter attack takes advantage of a design flaw in Windows's message-passing system whereby arbitrary code could be injected into any other running application or service in the same session, that makes use of a message loop. This could result in a privilege escalation exploit.

Comment: Thanks Steve.. Is there any example/link I can learn from? From where I can learn how to write such an application..